# Unable to download the dataset of curatedMetagenomicData package

Tags: r

I'm unable to download the datasets by using the curatedMetagenomicData packages. I have tried two methods, but it failed.

case 1

```
curatedMetagenomicData("AsnicarF_2017.relative_abundance", dryrun = FALSE, rownames = "short")
```

[image]

case 2

```
library(curatedMetagenomicData)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ExperimentHub))
eh = ExperimentHub()

myquery = query(eh, "curatedMetagenomicData")

myquery

View(mcols(myquery))

write.csv(mcols(myquery), file="curatedMetagenomicData_allrecords.csv")

head(myquery$tags)

grep("(?=HMP)(?=.*metaphlan)", myquery$title, perl=TRUE, val=TRUE)

grep("(?=.*stool)(?=.*metaphlan)", myquery$title, perl=TRUE, val=TRUE)

(lomannames = grep("LomanNJ_2013_Hi", myquery$title, perl=TRUE, val=TRUE))

(idx = grep("LomanNJ_2013_Hi", myquery$title, perl=TRUE))
loman.list = lapply(idx, function(i){
  return(myquery[[i]])
})
```

[image]

Is it because of the network?
Is it because of the dataset unable to access now?

I have changed the version of curatedMetagenomicData package or R.